# NodeJS Selenium Chrome Webdriver Connection Refused

Tags: javascript, node.js, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I'm new to NodeJS and Selenium Webdriver and I wanted to launch a simple test code:

```js
var webdriver = require("selenium-webdriver");
 
function createDriver() {
    var driver = new webdriver.Builder()
        .usingServer('http://localhost:4444/wd/hub')
        .withCapabilities(webdriver.Capabilities.chrome())
        .build();
    driver.manage().timeouts().setScriptTimeout(10000);
    return driver;
}
 
var driver = createDriver();
driver.get("http://www.google.com");
 
driver.getTitle().then(function (title) {
    console.log(title);
});
 
driver.quit();
```

I have everything setup, the chrome driver and the server launched.

But I'm getting this error:

> (node:3080) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise
>   rejection (rejection id: 2): WebDriverError:
>   java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect 
>   (node:3080) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are
>   deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled
>   will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
>   (node:3080) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise
>   rejection (rejection id: 3): WebDriverError:
>   java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect 
>   (node:3080) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection
>   (rejection id: 4): WebDriverError: java.net.ConnectException:
>   Connection refused: connect

Can you guys please help? Thanks!

Comment: Instead of http try https in driver.get() please, and let me know.

Comment: please format your code correctly

Comment: @SarthakSrivastava, even with https instead of http it returns the same error.. 
The Chrome browser pops up, but nothing's executed.

Answer (score 0):

Have you installed all the relevant modules including chromedriver using npm i --save-dev?

Are you able to access the localhost url manually?

Comment: Yes, all the modules are installed including Chromedriver
And I can access the localhost url manually

Comment: What version of Chrome are you using to run this, what is the file structure of your project?

Comment: Chrome version: Version 63.0.3239.132
 -- About the file structure it's a very simple project, I have in my folder the script file, the selenium server standalone and the chromedriver.exe

Comment: is chromedriver running for you? check by running: chromedriver -p 4444

Comment: Yes it's running, everything's good nad still, it returns the same error.. 
PS: I can access the localhost url manually so it's running perfectly

Comment: OK firstly try running a new RemoteWebDriver instance to it: 

WebDriver driver = new RemoteWebDriver(new URL("http://localhost:4444/wd/hub"), DesiredCapabilities.chrome());

If it doesn't start up then make sure the webdriver agent is running:
launchctl list | grep webdriverd
and if that returns nothing, then you need to launch it

Comment: The Webdriver runs perfectly there's no problem with it
It just refuses the connection I don't know why
WebDriverError: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect

Comment: OK may also be worth trying with another driver such as Safari to see if its a specific problem with Chromedriver